# .htaccess redirect - wildcard AND/OR syntax

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I updated a website to a new system, and now we have a ton of redirects to handle.

Many of them fall into the same general pattern - old links ending in .html or .php, with certain keywords (product names) in the URL.

Instead of writing an explicit redirect for each case (already up to 1500+, and still growing), I was thinking there's a way to handle them with an AND/OR statement.

For example:

If the OLD URL contains "SKU12345" AND ".html", it should be redirected to /products/SKUGROUP1/SKU12345.

This way, whether the old URL looks like

"/products/oldsubcategory/something/cool-widget-SKU12345.html"

**OR**
"/something/really-old-version-of-SKU-12345.html"

it should redirect to the same new page.

In other words, I want to catch any links that contain a specific product model/SKU/keyword, **AND** the extension .html or .php, and redirect them to the new URL (which doesn't have an ending).

I can't just say "if the old URL contains this SKU/keyword", because the new URLs also contain the SKU/keywords, and it would cause a redirect loop. It has to specifically contain .html/.php.

Is this possible to do? If so, can anyone show me the proper syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: This maybe of use if your using 2.4 or above https://blogs.apache.org/httpd/entry/new_in_httpd_2_4

Comment: That's a good pointer, but unfortunately:

1.) I'm not familiar with httpd :(

2.) There's only 1 example, and it's a non-www to www redirect.

3.) I can't seem to find any "htaccess generators" that actually utilize the if/else/elseif function :(

...so overall, just as clueless as I was before this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in root .htaccess to match both cases:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (^|[/-])AA99SKU1-?(\d*)\.(?:html?|php)$ /products/SKUGROUP1/AA99SKU1$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```

This will match both cases:

```
"/products/oldsubcategory/something/cool-widget-SKU12345.html" 
OR
"/something/really-old-version-of-SKU-12345.html"
```

Comment: anubhava: thank you, that will go a long way toward cleaning up the mess. Is there a way to make it match .html OR .php?

Comment: Nope, didn't actually work. Still getting the "page not found" page.

Comment: Make sure this is your very first rule and also tell what URL did you use for testing.

Comment: Yes, I placed it right at the beginning of the .htaccess file.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule -AA99SKU1-?(\d+)\.(?:html?|php)$ /products/SKUGROUP1/AA99SKU1$1 [L,NC,R=301]

I.e. the old URL was www.mysite.com/products/AA99SKU1.php, the new one is /products/SKUGROUP1/AA99SKU1 (no extension)

Comment: Very very close. The only thing that's left is that the resulting URL has an extra dash at the end. It should end with "AA99SKU1", but it ends with "AA99SKU1-".

Comment: try my updated answer after clearing your browser cache.